# Font-weight attribute is not working is this case

Tags: html, css

This is my css:

```
td{
        color: white;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 13vh;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-align: center; 
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: rgba(4,54,82,.62);
}
```

Everything worked as I expected exept for "font-weight" property. Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: What's wrong with the `font-weight`? What's not working as you expected?

Comment: It is not making my letters bold

Comment: @estebandruetta to have bold you have to put `700` or `bold` and not `300`

Answer (score 5):

You can [read more about font-weight here](http://htmldog.com/references/css/properties/font-weight/).

In my opinion, the value 300 for font-weight is really really hard for notice from normal (normal is 400). For easy notice, you might want to try the value larger than 700 or `font-weight:bold`.